# How do I get a for loop to work while searching a vector for objects that share elements with another vector in C++?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

I've got a C++ program with two input files and an output file. The first input file has a list of products (subclass stock), and the second input file has a list of orders. I've worked out how to deal with most of the problems that I've had, and I've gotten so close, but I need to read the items in the `arrOrders` vector, and compare them with the `orderTitle` and `stockLevel` in the `arrStock` vector. I've managed to get it to work for the first item in the order list, but I can't get it to work beyond there.

```
class Product {

public:
    std::string title, surname;
    long long int isbn;
    double  wholesalePrice;
    void setProductInfo(std::string, std::string, long long int, double);
    void setTitle(std::string);
    void setSurname(std::string);
    void setWholesalePrice(double);
    void setIsbn(long long int);
    double getWholesalePrice();
    long long int getIsbn();
    std::string getTitle();
    std::string getSurname();
    Product();
    ~Product();
    Product(std::string, std::string, long long int, double);
};

class Stock :public Product
{

public:
    double retailPrice;
    char bookFormat;
    int stockLevel;
    std::string calcRP;
    Stock(std::string, int, char, std::string, double, long long int, double);
    Stock();
    ~Stock();
    double getRetailPrice();
    char getBookFormat();
    int getStockLevel();
    void setStockLevel(int);
    void setBookFormat(char);
    void setRetailPrice(double);
};

class Order {

public:
    std::string orderTitle;
    int orderStock;
    Order(std::string, int);
    Order();
    ~Order();
    void setStock(int);
    void setTitle(std::string);
    std::string getTitle();
    int getStock();
};


void importBooks();
void runReport();
void newBook();
void delBook();
std::vector<Stock> arrStock{};
std::vector<Order> arrOrders{};
void checkStock();
//lots of code

//checkStock function
void checkStock()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("orders_v5.txt");
    
    Order anOrder;
    std::string orderTitle;
    int orderStock;

    inFile >> anOrder.orderTitle >> anOrder.orderStock;
    arrOrders.push_back(anOrder);

    std::cout << "#########################################################################################";       std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "                                      ORDER REPORT";      std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "#########################################################################################";       std::cout << std::endl;
    // code adapted from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < arrOrders.size(); k++)
    {
        orderTitle = arrOrders[k].getTitle();
        orderStock = arrOrders[k].getStock();
        std::vector<Stock>:: iterator test1 = find_if(arrStock.begin(), arrStock.end(), [&orderTitle](const Stock stock)->bool
            {
                for (unsigned int m = 0; m < arrStock.size(); m++)
                {
                    return stock.title == orderTitle;
                }
            });
        std::vector<Stock>::iterator test2 = find_if(arrStock.begin(), arrStock.end(), [&orderStock](const Stock stock)->bool
            {
                for (unsigned int m = 0; m < arrStock.size(); m++)
                {
                    return arrStock[m].getStockLevel() >= orderStock;
                }
            });
        if (test1 != arrStock.end())
        {
            if (test2 != arrStock.end())
            {
                std::cout << orderTitle << " is available at Biblioden and there is enough stock to fulfil your older.";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << orderTitle << " is available at Biblioden but there is not enough stock to fulfil your order.";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << orderTitle << " is not available at Biblioden.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do your `std::find_if` calls have embedded `for` loops in them?  The `find_if` does the "looping" automatically.  It seems all you need to do inside the lambda is to return whether the titles are the same.

Comment: Also, `Product` does not have a virtual destructor, thus deriving from it is dangerous and/or shouldn't be done.

Comment: Turn on warnings. Those fors in lambdas return at first iteration and fail to return anything when arrStock is empty so every compiler that is allowed will diagnose that.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, I thought I needed to have the embedded `for` loops because I need to filter for two different things and need to loop through the second array for each time I'm looping through the first array. What would a fix look like for inside the lamda? I'm terrible at terminology, so an example would be amazing. 

I genuinely can't process the concept of virtual constructors or even derivation at 3am so I'm going to get some sleep, but if you've got a link on hand that I could use to learn about it in the morning I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @ÖöTiib I've got warnings on and it says `"warning C4715: '<lambda_a54c7a87b2bb9f6997948829947b52cb>::operator()': not all control paths return a value"` but I assumed that would sort itself out once I worked out what the hell I'm doing... what could I learn from the warnings?

Comment: @crab_attack -- I suggest getting rid of all the `for` loops (maybe the entire code after you read in the data).  Start with using just `std::find_if` for the first thing you are trying to find.  Do you know what `std::find_if` does and what it returns?  Also, if you look at your current code in terms of what you're doing -- what if the number of items is 1000?  You would, for the first `find_if`, loop a max of a million times to search for whatever you're trying to find.  Wouldn't you call that inefficient (and maybe wrong)?

Comment: It would also help if you were consistent with the member variable names.  The `Order` class would be a little bit more clear if the member variable name was `stockLevel`, just like in the `Stock` class instead of `orderStock`.  The picture of what you are trying to do becomes more clear.

Comment: Oh geez I'm such a goose, I have fixed the member variable names, removed the completely unnecessary loops, changed it to a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop and now my loop is working properly, phew! I am now just trying to work out how to get my second condition to work properly. I don't want to be using a second iterator because that literally makes no sense, I want to retrieve a different attribute of the same vector object that the iterator function has found. How would I do that?